# the same record double in standard grid

Tags: acumatica

I dont' understand why I have 2 records in the grid with this code.
I have only one SOOrder with "CCG00010"

```
PXSelect<SOOrder,Where<SOOrderExt.usrabocmd,Equal<Current<ABONNEMENT.abonum>>>> CurrentAbocmd;
```

[image]